# Microsoft Sculpt keyboard malfunctioning (system conflict?)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, diagnostic, wireless-keyboard, software-conflict

I have Win7 x32 on my office desktop PC and recently I bought Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Desktop which consists of wireless mice, keyboard and numpad.
The communication between these input devices is performed via 2.4GHz transceiver (Microsoft ... v9.0).

So, I plugged transceiver and turned on the devices, Windows started auto-detection and it successed.

**However**, the keyboard seemed to be "dead", since typing produced no text on the screen (in notepad). So I got the microsoft recommendations list and checked everything. 
One of my next steps was installing Microsoft software for keyboard and mice management.
After reboot, **I found an interesting behavior** of the keyboard and numpad. When I pushed any button for the first time after reboot - it was okay, everything seemed to be nice (I checked caps, num, tried to type text (first letter was typed)), but **only for the first key press**.

After first key press several buttons are still functioning: calculator call, volume up/down/mute; *but nothing happens when pressing other keys*.

I also tested the devices on similiar PC (both DELL Optiplex 390, W7 x32, approximately same uptime) and everything was fine. So I came up with idea that there is some software conflict on my computer... which I don't know how to find and solve.

*I will highly appreciate any thoughts on how to solve the problem, or how to diagnoze it*.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: You did a good job of explaining your question. Is there another device (cordless phone, router, etc.) in the area which might be operating on he same channel? Did you install drivers from a CD or downloaded? Downloading them usually provided the latest ones.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so... And still, this behavior is too stable to be stipulated by another device. Drivers were downloaded automatically

Comment: for network stumblers. This is a very bad combo. First the adapter started malfunctioning, then the keyboard. Sculpt is awful. Ergonomic 4000 was super good and durable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright... after few days of diagnostics and testing on other PCs I think I found out what the problem was about.

First, here's the symptoms summary:

1. Keyboard/Mice is detected by OS.
2. Keyboard seems to be malfunctioning, maybe some keys are still functioning (in my case: calculator call, volume up/down/mute).
3. Keyboard works fine before OS is loaded (try F8 for extended loading menu of Windows, try arrows to navigate the option - in my case it was okay, but it depends on BIOS and it's options of loading USB drivers).

My first conclusion, as mentioned above, was some conflict.
However in my case **the problem was generally conditioned by DeviceLock utility**.
This utility is kind of Anti-anti-anti-"malicous things you can do with USB port", which also includes Anti-keylogger and etc stuff.

So the **solution** in my case is handling the situation with this utility, analogously with this tickets:

1.[Microsoft Wireless Keyboard](http://www.devicelock.com/support/kb_view.html?ID=17318&find_message=&find_kb_category_id=1108)

2.[Logitech diNovo](http://www.devicelock.com/support/kb_view.html?ID=17318&find_message=&find_kb_category_id=1108)

... **or simly get rid of this anti-anti-anti software**, which unfortunately impossible in the office for most of us :)

Comment: Nice catch, though, not my cause of trouble. I don't have the DeviceLock tool, but do have this same problem. I actually had that same issue with the mouse as well, but it seem to have gone away after I've put in the new batteries.

Answer (score 5):

I have one of these and have noticed that plugging the receiver into a 10cm usb extension cable massively improves the reliability of the signal , before doing this i would get random cutouts and lags. This also helps for my Logitech wireless mouse. The battery life for these devices is also improved.

I can only guess that the transmission pattern was not well thought out to escape the electromagnetic sweet nothings my computer seems to intimidating it with.

Whilst this sounds unscientific i have noticed this with both my laptop and hub combo and the desktop where i used to work. Both run linux but this should not make a difference as this behaviour was observed when controlling the BIOS as well.

Comment: This question inspired me to simply try a different USB port, which seemed to fix it as well. That may be a good thing to attempt before you commit to a USB extender